# Issues with macros and formulas in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having problems when inserting a formula from a macro in Excel. I managed to insert exactly the same value that I have on another cell where the formula is working perfectly. It always says #¿NAME? unless I press F2 and Enter. I checked and rechecked the calculation mode and is not Manual, is set to automatic but this formulas doesn't work at all. The method SendKeys "{f2}" SendKeys "{enter}" seems to work but it's horrible and not "seamless".

I've tried with different formulas (from simpler to more complex) and every time a tried any function inside my formula just doesn't work. The only way I insert a working formula is just using numbers (ex. "=1+1" and stuff like that) but when using any function for ex. "=SUM(A1:A5)" just don't work (unless pressing F2 and Enter).

I don't understand why having exactly the same "text" inserted as Formula it just don't work.
What can I do to solve this???
Thanx in advance

Comment: It's always best to show your code.

Comment: This is my code: Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Formula = "=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(" & "B" & laststr & " , Datos!A2:E52, 3), """")" as I said it insert the text perfectly on the selected cell but for some reason Excel is not "executing" the code inside that cell unless pressing F2 and Enter

Comment: What formatting you have applied to the cells where you are putting the formulas, Text?

Comment: I **think** you need to use FormulaLocal to insert locale-dependent formulas.

Comment: I'm doing this to a "brand new" sheet so it's set to General.

Comment: I'm using Excel in Spanish, that's why the formula names are in that language.

Comment: Thanx YoyE3K!!! Using FormulaLocal seems to work (so far)

Comment: FWIW using `FormulaLocal` makes your *code* locale-dependent, which means if any of your users runs the macro on another machine configured in another locale, *they* will be getting the `#NAME!` errors. To avoid this use `.Formula` and use the English function names in VBA. That way a French client will see `=SOMME`, an English one will see `=SUM` and a Spanish one will see whatever the Spanish is for the SUM formula. =)

Comment: @Monster - Can you "unaccept" my answer please, and accept your own one instead - as Mat's Mug has pointed out, my answer is a stupid idea.

Comment: @YowE3K that's not what I said... ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I paraphrased (because it **is** a stupid idea, even if you didn't say it)

Comment: @YowE3K you could always edit your answer.. "just do it the wrong way" -style ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [the answer by Monster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376054/6535336) for the correct solution to the problem.

I have to leave this answer here until it is "unaccepted", and then I will be able to delete it.

---

To enter locale-dependent formulas, you need to use `FormulaLocal`:

```
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).FormulaLocal = "=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(B" & laststr & " , Datos!A2:E52, 3), """")"
```

Comment: This feels like a horrible idea (code is no longer portable), but +1 for "fixing" the immediate problem.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Good point - I'll try to get the OP to unaccept the answer so that I can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your replies!!!

Using FormulaLocal works great!!! What I did was to "translate" the functions names and done!

```
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & "B" & laststr & " , Datos!A2:E52, 3), """")"
```