# What is the difference between ReferTo and RefersToLocal?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, when adding a named range programmatically, I can do it either as:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="FirstName", RefersTo:="=$B$2"
```

or as:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="FirstName", RefersToLocal:="=$B$2"
```

Now, can anyone tell me the difference between `RefersTo` and `RefersToLocal`? They seem to be doing the same thing, and the Excel documentation doesn't explain much either. (It says the latter uses '*localized text*' but does not explain what that means.)

Comment: Probably if it was referring to something like `=DAY(NOW())` then in the Portugese version (as an example) it would be `RefersTo:="=DAY(NOW())"` or `RefersToLocal:="=DIA(AGORA())"` (But, not having a non-English version of Excel, I can't really confirm that.)  It won't matter much if you are just referring to a cell address, that will be the same in all languages.  (Compare this with `Formula` and `FormulaLocal`.)

Comment: @YowE3K Predefined VBA function names are the same everywhere (ie. user language independent.) And your custom VBA functions are named by you and should not be altered by Excel.

Comment: From MSDN Documentation, main difference is which language is being used. [Name.RefersTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/name-refersto-property-excel) is language of the macro, whereas [Name.RefersToLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/name-referstolocal-property-excel) is language of the user. It's very hard to actually give example unless multiple languages of office/Windows is used.

Comment: @PatricK Unfortuinately I don't know what that means. RefersTo points to somewhere in your code, or a function, or a literal value. What does that got to do with languages?

Comment: @SFLee Can't really tell as I only have English version. As YowE3K said, probably if a Name has formulas using English version, then in a non-English Excel, the RefersToLocal may display in users Office
 Installed language.

Comment: @SFLee The function names in Excel formulas (such as used in `Formula` and `RefersTo`) are Excel function names, not VBA function names.  The `FormulaLocal` string would use the user's local language names (such as a formula of `=DIA(AGORA())` in the Portugese version of Excel) while the `Formula` string would use the US-EN (or is that EN-US? I always forget) `=DAY(NOW())`.  The same thing using VBA functions would also (in this particular example) be `Day(Now())`, and that would **not** be language specific.

Comment: @SFLee This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43374910/6535336) shows an example where I actually gave an answer showing how to use `FormulaLocal` (but then the OP decided to translate the formula to English, which was a better idea anyway because it makes the workbook portable to other locales).

Comment: @YowE3K Please post your initial comment as an answer so we can close this question. I have verified and confirm your comment to be correct (I have multiple non-English languages installed).

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Formula` allows VBA code to write Excel formulas using a US English syntax, while `FormulaLocal` allows VBA code to write the formulas using the user's current language settings.  (And there are also `FormulaR1C1` and `FormulaR1C1Local` properties to allow entry of formulas in R1C1 notation.)

In a similar way, `RefersTo` allows the entry of formulas for "named ranges" (which can actually be more than just a reference to a range) using US English syntax, while `RefersToLocal` allows the use of the local language.  (And there are also `RefersToR1C1` and `RefersToR1C1Local` properties to allow entry of formulas for "named ranges" in R1C1 notation.)

So in Spanish Excel, this:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=DAY(NOW())"
```

is equivalent to:

```
Range("A1").FormulaLocal = "=DIA(AHORA())"
```

and this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TodaysDayOfMonth", RefersTo:="=DAY(NOW())"
```

is equivalent to:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TodaysDayOfMonth", RefersToLocal:="=DIA(AHORA())"
```

---

Those "range names" may look strange, but can come in useful because they can be used in VBA as

```
... = Range("TodaysDayOfMonth")
```

or in Excel as

```
=IF(TodaysDayOfMonth=15,1,0)*A5
```

without the need to actually do that `DAY(NOW())` calculation within an actual cell.

Comment: I'm surprised that Microsoft will actually go and create multiple languages for function names, something that doesn't happen in any other programming languages. But thanks for finding this out for me.

Comment: @SFLee Most people don't class Excel formulas as "programming".  Excel would lose a huge chunk of its target market if all of its users had to learn English in order to use it.  (Most applications intended for an international market are set up with all text values stored in language specific libraries, so that the software house just needs to ship a different DLL suited to the target language - the underlying code doesn't change at all.)  VBA, on the other hand, **is** in English, just as most other programming languages.

Comment: You miss my point. Whether it is a proper programming language (C++, Java, C#), or a scripting language (JavaScript, VB Script, PHP), or a macro language (VBA), or even an application specific scripting language (InstallScript), it is unusual for the language to be multi-lingual, otherwise you have to create different parsers for each. You can argue that only the function names are multi-lingual (like this case here), but even that is very unusual. Usually only displayed texts in an application is multilingual, not the programming/scripting/macro language. Hence my surprise.

Comment: @SFLee But the formulas **are** displayed texts.  I'm pretty certain (although can't guarantee it), that behind the scenes Excel will be saving the formulas entered by the user in EN-US format so that the workbook can be opened in another user's language and see the formulas expressed in their own language instead of the language of the original user.  The `FormulaLocal` (and `RefersToLocal`) property will just invoke the translation routines used by Excel to convert normal user input into EN-US, and then continue processing using `Formula`.

Comment: Even if Excel does it that way, it is still just Excel that's doing it. No other software (outside Office) I know does that kind of thing. Also, when I say displayed text, I don't mean the formulas, I mean the displayed text *after* evaluating/calculating the formulas, as well as the displayed text within the application, such as the words in the menu bar.